# How to set a specific CGPoint as the centre of UIImageView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, core-image

I have s specific CGPoint that I would like my UIImageView to have as its centre.  I am not sure how to do this.  Below is my attempt:

```
var firstDotView: UIView?
let dotSize: CGFloat = 20
@IBOutlet weak var imgPreViewOutlet: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad(){

    firstDotView = UIView.init()
    firstDotView?.frame = CGRect.init(x: 60, y: 60, width: dotSize, height: dotSize)
    firstDotView?.center = CGPoint.init(x: 60, y: 60)

    drawFirstDot()
    imgPreViewOutlet.addSubview(firstDotView!)

} 


// DRAW ROUND CIRCLE
func drawFirstDot() -> Void {
    let layer = CAShapeLayer.init()
    layer.path = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: firstDotView!.bounds, cornerRadius: 50).cgPath
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    firstDotView?.layer.addSublayer(layer)
}
```

Comment: Do you want a single dot or a circle with a radius of 20?

Comment: i would like a circle with diameter of 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like so:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let firstDotView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: imgPreViewOutlet.bounds.width/2 - dotSize/2,
                                            y: imgPreViewOutlet.bounds.height/2 - dotSize/2,
                                            width: dotSize,
                                            height: dotSize))
    firstDotView.layer.cornerRadius  = dotSize/2
    firstDotView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    firstDotView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imgPreViewOutlet.addSubview(firstDotView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
let dotSize = 20
let firstDotView = UIView()
firstDotView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: dotSize, height: dotSize)
firstDotView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
firstDotView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
firstDotView.center = imageView.center

view.addSubview(firstDotView)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `imageView.layer.position = CGPoint(x: 60, y: 60)`

`layer.position` is relative to `anchorPoint` which by default is center of layer's content.

Answer (score 0):

if I'm not wrong, you want to add firstDotView somewhere on the parent view, then change imgPreViewOutlet center to be the same as firstDotView center.

first add the firstDotView as a subView to the parent view not to the imgPreViewOutlet, then set imgPreViewOutlet center to be equal to firstDotView center

replace

```
imgPreViewOutlet.addSubview(firstDotView!)
```

with

```
    view.addSubview(firstDotView!)
    imgPreViewOutlet.center = firstDotView!.centerde here
```